# Android Floating Profile Image Outside Fragment/Activity in XML

Tags: android, user-interface, user-profile, bottom-sheet

I am trying to build a profile ui such that the user image is just outside/floating on top of the remaining content like in this image.

[image]

I have used a bottom sheet dialog fragment and created the necessary xml widgets but it doesn't appear like this. How do I stack this type of ui.

Here's my xml implementation so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:gravity="bottom"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/infoCIV"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_players"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/date_dialog_bkg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/playerTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@drawable/tabs_underline_bkg"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/playerVP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playerTabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which layout do I use to achieve this ui. I've tried replacing the main Relative Layout with a Frame Layout but not worked the way I want it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the resulting output of this xml and contribution from comments in contrast with the desired output above:
[image]

and where the fragment is called from in adapter code:

```
 viewholder.playerRootLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PlayerInfoFragment fragment = new PlayerInfoFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(PLAYER_KEY_IMAGE_URL, players.getImageURL());
            String fullName = players.getFirstName() + " " + players.getLastName();
            bundle.putString(PLAYER_KEY_NAME, fullName);
            bundle.putString(PLAYER_KEY_ADDRESS, players.getAddress());
            bundle.putString(PLAYER_KEY_STATE, players.getStatePlayer());
//                bundle.putString(KEY_, players.);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar);
            fragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "PlayerInfoFragment");
        }
    });
```

The fragment java file has only xml objects initializing and the tab layout fragments added using `findviewbyid() and viewpageradapter to add fragments`

Comment: What result do you get? add here xml code of your bottom sheet dialog

Comment: This is the xml code. The output renders well but it has the image inside unlike in the image above. @VadimEksler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the answer: 
Add to your style this:

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and to your java class `CustomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment` this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme);
}
```

Comment: I have done that when adding the fragment in my adapter code like fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar);

Comment: It work? you add `setStyle()` to your class that extends from BottomSheetDialogFragment ?

Comment: second parameter must be your custom style that will override default style of BottomSheet.Modal

Comment: Yes It did but the image background is not transparent, its a fragment and I have added transparent background to both this and its parent activity.

Comment: Just like the image above, the list is not visible and when swiping out the sheet, just a white background at the top and till it's completely out of the view

Comment: The list should occupy the background, how do I make this work, thank you

Comment: I used the android material styles but my class extends a custom BottomSheet class which adds the rounded border to all places where I implement bottom sheet. I want to add transparency to only this fragment

Comment: I don't understand, your problem was that your circle image wasn't separated from other content? it fixed now?

Comment: It is separated but I want the circle image surrounding background at the top to be transparent and show the underlying activity screen only for the image background.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to make `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your RelativeLayout, and also remove bottom from gravity of LinearLayout parent of image.

Comment: you need to add to post java file of your fragment and image result that you get

Comment: I have edited the question, please have another look. Thank you

Comment: this is your problem - `fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar);` this fragment have separated class?

Comment: you need to add customStyle like in my answer, and make it after show method.

Comment: Please I need to reach out to you on sth android related. How do we get in touch? Thank you sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185347/discussion-between-vadim-eksler-and-darth-plagueris).