# Android Custom shape of BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to do something like on the screen below using BottomSheetDialogFragment. Is that even possible? I know it is possible in BottomNavigationView by overriding onDraw method but I can't figure if and how can I do it in BottomSheetDialogFragment.
Cheers

[image: Image of the custom shape of BottomSheedDialogFragment]

## Edit

Maybe I'll specify. This half-circle must be transparent, because inside it there will be button

[Specify of previous picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4TVH.png)

Comment: This is pretty much possible with layout only You can set a `Circular view` as anchor view on top . Give it a TRY [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043351/half-circle-shape-not-work).

Comment: It is possible, you can try following this tutorial https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7

Comment: @DemiDust I followed this tutorial but it is for BottomNavigationView only, but I have to do something like that but for BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: Yes it possible. My suggestion is to use standard bottom sheets and not modal, also take a look this my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53810362/7917629 it can helps.